# How to show out of stock product next due date in Magento 2.2.2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2, plugin, out-of-stock

How to show `out of stock products` with next due date for Product availability on market. I am using Magento 2.2.2.

I need free plugins and instructions only because I am not good with coding.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for the plugins right?

So, Some extensions are available in online and they are paid versions.

1. [Anowave Product Custom Stock Status](http://www.anowave.com/marketplace/magento-2-extensions/magento-2-product-custom-stock-status/)
2. [BELVG Product Custom Stock Status](https://store.belvg.com/custom-stock-status-for-magento-2-0.html)
3. [CMSIDEAS.NET Product Custom Stock Status](https://cmsideas.net/magento-2-custom-stock-status.html)
4. [Magecomp Product Custom Stock Status](https://magecomp.com/magento-2-custom-stock-status.html)
5. [Amasty Product Custom Stock Status](https://amasty.com/custom-stock-status-for-magento-2.html)

Custom Stock Status for Magento 2 allows for extending the default stock status message in Magento and adding new custom stock status messages. By default, Magento shows either "In Stock" or "Out of Stock".

These extensions allows for creating additional stock status messages such as "Available in 1 week" or "Less than 5 remaining"